# Differences in Affiliation Data GA4 Vs UA

Tags: google, google-analytics, google-analytics-4, data

I have noticed a significant difference in the affiliation data for almost all of my clients when it comes to reporting Affiliation data (users/sessions/revenue).

Here is an example:

UA: [image]

GA4: [image]

Has anyone else experienced this? What was the issue?